# A question regarding the definition of localization of ring

Tags: localization

Let $S$ be a multiplicative system. Then the localization of $R$ is defined by an equivalence relation on $R \times S$.
The relation is $(a,b) \sim (c,d)$ if there is an $s \in S$ such $s(ad-bc)=0$.

Regarding this, I can't show that transitivity works. Could anyone show me how to prove that $(a,b) \sim (c,d)$ and $(c,d) \sim (e,f)$ then $(a,b) \sim (e,f)$?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $(a,b) \sim (c,d)$ and $(c,d) \sim (e,f)$, so that there are $s$ and $t$ in $S$, with $s(ad-bc) = t(cf-de) = 0$. Since $S$ is multiplicative, and $d,s,t \in S$ we have $dst \in S$, and

$$ dst (af-be) = tf(sad) - bs(tde) = tf(sbc) - bs(tcf)=0.$$

Comment: oh, I was so foolish....Thank you :)